# How to fetch all the records and display info on the right. Depending on value from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to send a request form to the local warehouses. This request has an ID (request ID). The form contains shortlisted warehouses (as products because these warehouses will only stock that specific product). Depending on the request, chk boxes are ticked and the form is submitted to those specific warehouses.  The warehouse users, then fill the form by selected yes or no and submits the form again to us.

So far I am able to to get the form but I am not able to  link the results returned back to this request ID. RequestID is the PK of Request table and FK in SendRequest Table.

A request can be send more than 1 time in a day by the same user or many users to find out if the stock has arrived.

Normal left join query fetches the results, but the status yes/no gets linked with other request ID as well.

I also tried with left join query by using the where clause to the requestID, then the form to send the request gets disappeared.

Any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

query:

```
    Select request.ID, request.Name, request.Phone, request.email,
    request.Disabled, request_request_status.r_id,  
    request_request_status.comments,
    FROM request
    LEFT JOIN request_request_status on request_request_status.r_id = request.ID
    WHERE request.Disabled = 0 and request.shortList = 1 
    Order by request.Name ASC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
DB::table('carrier')->select('carrier.ID','carrier.Name', 'carrier.Phone', 'carrier.email',
    'carrier.Disabled', 'request_request_status.r_id','request_request_status.comments')
    ->join('request_request_status', 'request_request_status.r_id', '=', 'carrier.ID')
    ->where('carrier.Disabled','=',0)
    ->where('carrier.shortList','=',1)
    ->orderBy('carrier.Name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: actually the carrier table is request. I was trying something but didnt work and forgot to change it back to request (table).I was trying the query in workbench so not in the laravel format. I have updated the qt.

Comment: thanks, but still having an error: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\where()`

Comment: i tried it but it gave me same results that I was getting it earlier.